# What is GeliyooBot/1.0 every day in my website?

Tags: web-crawler

I need to ask some question about geliyoobot, in my website first time coming sitemap, after coming robots than now I see in may url please help me about this what is this bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geliyoo#Search_Engine

Geliyoo Search, a web search engine, is the company's most popular service. Geliyoo has also developed its own search engine crawler, Geliyoo Spider. (GeliyooBot/1.0), This is the first Turkish search engine bot, GeliyooBot/1.0, was created to build a searchable index for the Geliyoo Search engine. It gives the webmaster the ability to restrict the information on their site available to a GeliyooBot, or to another well-behaved spider, by using the appropriate commands in a robots.txt file, or by adding the meta tag  to the web page. Geliyoo Spider requests to Web servers are identifiable by a user-agent string containing "GeliyooBot" and by a host address containing "geliyoo.com".